# Ridge regression vs Lasso Regression

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, lasso-regression

Is Lasso regression or Elastic-net regression always better than the ridge regression?

I've conducted these regressions on a few data sets and I've always got the same result that the mean squared error is the least in lasso regression. Is this a mere coincidence or is this true in any case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the topic, James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani write in their book "An Introduktion to Statistical Learning":

> These two examples illustrate that neither ridge regression nor the
> lasso will universally dominate the other. In general, one might expect
> the lasso to perform better in a setting where a relatively small
> number of predictorshave substantial coefficients, and the remaining
> predictors have coefficients that are very small or that equal zero.
> Ridge regression will perform better when the response is a function of
> many predictors, all with coefficients of roughly equal size. However,
> the number of predictors that is related to the response is never
> known apriori for real data sets. A technique such as cross-validation
> can be used in order to determine which approach is betteron a
> particular data set. (chapter 6.2)

Answer (score 2):

It's different for each problem. In lasso regression, algorithm is trying to remove the extra features that doesn't have any use which sounds better because we can train with less data very nicely as well but the processing is a little bit harder, but in ridge regression the algorithm is trying to make those extra features less effective but not removing them completely which is easier to process.